# Paramiko hangs when running on 150+ servers while running simple commands

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to run multiple commands on bunch of remote servers using python's Paramiko module.

The commands I'm trying to run are simple commands, such as cat, lspci(with grep) and also small script with only 1 line output.

The thing is, if I provide few machines (~50), it works just fine.
The problem starts when I try run the script on many machines.

```
try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username='root', password='pass')
    transport = ssh.get_transport()
    channel = transport.open_session()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        line = line.strip() 
        sheet1.write(row_line,0,host,style_cell) # writing to xls file
        sheet1.write(row_line,1,line,style_cell) # writing to xls file

    while channel.recv_ready():
        channel.recv(1024)

    ssh.close()

expect:
    print stdout
    print stderr
```

This is the stdout,stderr I get:

```
paramiko.ChannelFile from paramiko.Channel 2 (EOF received) (open) window=2097152
paramiko.Transport at 0xce44c9d0L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 2 open channel(s))
```

Please advice,

Thanks!

Comment: Enable paramiko debug logging to see if you can elicit more information from the paramiko module. `logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with specific servers. Try outputting which server it is that causes errors and see if you can recreate the problem if running the script only with that specific server.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I tried running the commands on the hosts that failed and the command ended successfully...